# block eval() in CSP header Angular 8 project

Tags: javascript, angular, eval, content-security-policy

Can I block the **eval** function in CSP-Header for a Angular project (when I don't use it directly) or a there any side effects which would lead to errors when the project is deployed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the default-src or script-src directives eval will be blocked unless you allow it with 'unsafe-eval'. If eval, setTimeout, setInterval or new Function is being called in any script it will be blocked. If you are concerned that something may break run Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only for a while and check the reports that are sent.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: so if set script-src and don't allow 'unsafe-eval' and than use setTimeout within my Angular App - this will get blocked?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. Without `'unsafe-eval'` token all eval-expressions will be blocked. But there is one *note* for `setTimeout()` / `SetInterval()` - these counted as eval-expressions **only** if executed function is passed in argument as [text string](https://csplite.com/csp/test153/#test). If anonymous func or func name is passed - `setTimeout()` / `SetInterval()` is treated as safe and is not blocked.